# Friendly formatter for webpack-dev-server errors?

Tags: webpack, eslint

What I am looking for is a functionality like [eslint-friendly-formatter](https://github.com/royriojas/eslint-friendly-formatter). This tool creates clickable/linked errors in the console, to directly jump to the affected position in code when clicked.

**My question**

Does *webpack-dev-server* provide such a feature? Or are there any plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you are looking for, but [Jarvis](https://github.com/zouhir/jarvis) provides

> Google or Stackoverflow Search for programming errors in 1 button click.

Note: I'm not affiliated, but this is really useful.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, but a quite useful tool anyway.